# Unique anchor links with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some `jQuery`code that targets all anchor links that are clicked.

```
    <a href="contact-us.php#media">Media Enquiries</a>
    <a href="#testimonials" class="btn">See Why</a>
```

**Jquery code**

```
   $('a[href*=#]').on('click', function(event){ 
        event.preventDefault();
        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$(this.hash).offset().top}, 500);
    });
```

However if the link is another page "contact-us.php#media" it does not work because it is expecting it to be the same page.

How can I change the code to still target all # links but ignore it if it is linking to another page?

Answer (score 1):

If `href` attribute of the all target elements start with `#` then you can use the *Attribute Starts With* selector.

```
$('a[href^=#]')
```

Another option is checking the pathname of anchors:

```
$('a[href*=#]').filter(function() {
   return this.pathname === location.pathname;
}).on('click', ...);
```

The above snippet just checks the pathname, if you want to check the hostnames as well, you can add another condition to the filter method, i.e: `&& this.hostname === location.hostname`

Answer (score 0):

Found this that specifically targets the same page.

[Performs a smooth page scroll to an anchor on the same page](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/)